# How can I write jasmine test for angular controller and service like this?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I'm stuck for hours for this and it's because I'm new to Jasmine and Angularjs. Basically, I have this controller.

```
angular.module('toadlane.controllers', []).
    controller('MainController', function($scope, $http, SomeService) {

        var promise = SomeService.getObjects();

        promise.then(function(data) {
            if(data.length > 0) {
                $scope.objs = data;
            } else {
                $scope.message = "Please come back soon";
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I write a Jasmine test to mock SomeService to stub out `data` and simulate if there's data the `scope`'s length should not be 0 and if `data` is [] the message should be "Please come back soon".

```
'use strict';

describe('controllers', function () {
    var scope, someService;
    beforeEach(module('services'));
    beforeEach(module('controllers'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (SomeService) {
        someService = SomeService;

        var callback = jasmine.createSpy();
        someService.getObjs().then(callback);
    }));

    it('should return some objs', inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        expect($controller('MainController', {$scope: scope, SomeService : someService})).toBeTruthy();

        expect(scope.objs.length).toEqual(2);
    }));

    it('should return no objs', inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        expect($controller('MainController', {$scope: scope, SomeService : someService})).toBeTruthy();


        expect(scope.message).toEqual("Please come back soon");
    }));

});
```

The tests are not finished because I don't know how to stub `then` from `promise`

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't offer a longer answer at the moment, but I would stub `SomeService.getObjs` to be a fake function that returns a custom promise (made with `$q`) that you control.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, but if you could give me the example code later. That'd be great.

Comment: Also I tried to do that, but I don't know how to stub callback function argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Defers can be tested by mocking promises with functions which return object with chained methods. In this case mocked `SomeService.getObjs` should return an object with method `then`.

In order to do this add another one `beforeEach` statement:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('SomeService', {
    getObjs: function () {
      return {
        then: function (callback) {
          // mockedResponseData is passed to callback
          callback(mockedResponseData);
        }
      };
    }
  }));
```

Mocked service will immediately load result in existing promise callback function.