# Testing controller with injected service inside angularJS with jasmine

Tags: testing, angularjs, tdd, jasmine, code-injection

I am trying to understand how to test my code with jasmine and angularJS. I wrote a test project with a controller and an injected service. Now i want to test the controller and tried to mock the injected service. But i didn’t found a way to test the function “Arrived” from my controller. Here’s my jsfiddle: ***http://jsfiddle.net/2fwxS/***

**controller.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyService', function ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.User = {};
    $scope.HasUserArrived = false;
    $scope.Arrived = function(firstname, lastname) {
    $scope.HasUserArrived = MyService.Arrive(firstname, lastname);
    return $scope.HasUserArrived;
    }
}]);
```

**services.js:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp.services', []).
  value('version', '0.1');

myApp.factory('MyService', [function () {
    return {
        HasArrived: false,
        Arrive: function (firstname, lastname) {
            this.HasArrived = false;

            if (firstname && lastname) {
                this.HasArrived = true;
            }

            console.log("User has arrived: " + this.HasArrived);
            return this.HasArrived;
        }
    }
}]);
```

I found some similar explanations where $provide could be the correct solution ([How can I write jasmine test for angular controller and service like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255759/how-can-i-write-jasmine-test-for-angular-controller-and-service-like-this)) or createSpy ([How do you mock Angular service that is a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531904/how-do-you-mock-angular-service-that-is-a-function)) but I wasn’t able to understand when I need $provider.factory or $provider.value or when should I use createSpy?

I would appreciate if someone could help me to understand the differences and gets the deactivated code in my jsFiddle (***http://jsfiddle.net/2fwxS/***) example up and running...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `$provide.value` in order to replace the original service instance with a mocked one:

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    var service = { 
        Arrive: function (firstname, lastname) {
            if (firstname && lastname) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
    $provide.value('MyService', service);
}));
```

I really don't know why `$provide.value` works but `$provide.factory` doesn't. I'll try to take a look at the Angular code later so I can figure it out. I'll update this answer if I find out something.

About spies, you should use them if you want to test that your mocks are being used the way they are supposed to. That includes checking parameters and invocations. Here's your code changed to use a spy:

```
it('checks that Arrived is correctly used', function() {
    // Arrange
    spyOn(service, 'Arrive');

    // Act
    scope.Arrived('Franz', 'Kafka');

    // Assert
    expect(service.Arrive).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Franz', 'Kafka');
});
```

Here's your fixed [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fwxS/3/).

Comment: Sorry for my late response!
@Michael Thank you for the answer and the corrected jsFiddle. With those little changes i was able to run my tests successfully!

Indeed it would be nice to know why factory doesn't work.

Comment: And my colleague and i are interested if there is also a way to test the service inside this example instead of mocking the service. We know we should test the service separately but we were wondering if testing the service inside this example could be possible...

Comment: You can get away with mocking out the service in order to test the controller if the service is very simple and you can safely predict its behavior, thus minimizing the odds of breaking the controller tests because of an error in the service implementation. But, if you do that you'll be testing the controller, not the service. You should still test the service separately so you can ensure it works the way it's supposed to.

Comment: Out of curiosity - if another service, which is injected in the same test / describe block uses the argument named 'MyService' then both of them will have it the same? Excuse my ignorance, but I'm just starting with Jasmine and Angularjs - I'm trying to understand it all and I'm new to TDD in general.

Comment: @SpencerMark Yes. Every service that is instantiated after the `$provide.value('MyService', service);` line will get a mocked instance of MyService.