# Angularjs Unit Test Not Hitting then part of controller after calling service in AngularJS & testing using Karma & Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have Angular service which calling web api method:

`services.service('loginService', function ($http) { this.loginAction = function                (userInfo) { console.log(userInfo);`

```
    return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'url of web api service',
    params: userInfo

 } );
```

}
});

i have Controller which call this service & get data in then block

```
  adminApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope','loginService','localStorageService','$location', function ($scope, loginService, localStorageService, $location) {

$scope.login = function (isValid) {
    var userData = { 'username': $scope.username, 'password': $scope.password };
    if (isValid) {

        loginService.loginAction(userData).then(

            function (response) {

                        console.log(response);                
                        if (response.data.Success) {
                            alert("Success !!!!");
                            IsAdminMenu = true;
                            localStorageService.clearAll();
                            localStorageService.set('Token', response.data.Data);

                            $scope = $scope || angular.element(document).scope();
                            if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                                //this will kickstart angular if to notice the change
                                $scope.$apply();
                            }
                            $location.path('/dashboard/');
                        }
                        else {
                           alert(response.data.Data);
                        }
                    }, function (error) {
                        alert('Got the error');
                    });
    }
}
```

}
]);

its work fine but when i tested this controller using unit test written using karma + Jasmine

```
describe('LogIn in Progress....', function () {
var scope, $controller, ctrl, $rootScope;//use this scope in tests

   //mock Application to allow us to inject our own dependencies
    beforeEach(module('adminApp'));
   //mock the controller for the same reason and include $rootScope and $controller
   beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    //create an empty scope
     scope = $rootScope.$new();

    //declare the controller and inject our empty scope
    ctrl = $controller('loginController', { $scope: scope });
}));
// tests start here
it('Check for Valid LogIn', function () {

    scope.username = 'admin';
    scope.password = 'test12';

    scope.login(true);


   expect(scope.IsAdminMenu).toEqual(true);
});
```

});

when i run this it is not going into .then part of controller
 console.log(response);   not getting response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe('myApp', function () {
    var scope,
        controller,
        mockLoginService = {},
        mockLocalStorageService = {},
        $q,
        $location;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('loginService', mockLoginService);
            $provide.value('localStorageService', mockLocalStorageService);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$q_, _$location_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('loginController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
        $q = _$q_;
        $location = _$location_;
    }));

    describe('MyCtrl', function () {
        var loginActionDefer;

        beforeEach(function () {
            loginActionDefer = $q.defer();
            mockLoginService.loginAction = jasmine.createSpy('loginService.loginAction').andReturn(loginActionDefer.promise);
            mockLocalStorageService.clearAll = jasmine.createSpy('localStorageService.clearAll');
            mockLocalStorageService.set = jasmine.createSpy('localStorageService.set');
        });

        it('checks for Valid LogIn', function () {
            var stubName = 'admin',
                stubPassword = 'test12'

            scope.username = stubName;
            scope.password = stubPassword;

            scope.login(true);

            expect(mockLoginService.loginAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ username: stubName, password: stubPassword });

            loginActionDefer.resolve( {data: {Success: true}} );
            scope.$digest();

            expect(scope.IsAdminMenu).toEqual(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Jasmine 1.3 - mocked example - http://jsfiddle.net/vB9Kt/1/

Comment: what modification should i do in my test

Comment: you must merge my code with your test and also incjet $q service.

Comment: geetting error on this line loginService.loginAction = jasmine.createSpy('loginService.loginAction').and.returnValue(action.promise);   i am using jasmine jasmine-version:1.3.1 revision 1354556913

Comment: I've added note that this is for Jasmine 2.0
In Jasmine 1.3 you have to write .andReturnValue(action.promise) (without dot between `and` and `returnValue`

For better readibility you can change `it('Check for` to `it('Checks for` as `it` is in 3-rd person

Comment: i have changed it but on same line it showing me...        ReferenceError: loginService is not defined

Comment: I see, you haven't inject loginService to test - take a while and read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175720/testing-controller-with-injected-service-inside-angularjs-with-jasmine

Comment: ok i'll read it,if possible try to edit my test code & post it.because i have already spent 1 n 1/2 day & its urgent

Comment: i want to test it with data return from web api service.if i provide different username & password which is not present in database still test result got success

Comment: If you want check connection with database - this is not a unit test - this will be **e2e** test and should be written in different way.

To check reject branch change line `loginActionDefer.resolve( {data: {Success: true}} );` to `loginActionDefer.reject();`

Comment: k..thanx alot...one more question doctorModule.controller('addDoctorController', ['$scope', 'commonBL', 'getLookups', '$routeParams', function ($scope, commonBL, getLookups, $routeParams) {  getLookups.getLookups('PhoneType').then
       (
           function (response) { $scope.formData.PhoneType = response.data;
 $scope.formData.PhoneType.forEach(function (value) {
 if (value.Value == "WP")
                       $scope.ContactTypeId = value.LookupId;
               });InitialServiceCall--;
               _editCall();
           }); ..how to test this

Comment: i am getting         Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $route
Params   ...i tried your solution with some changes

Comment: If you are satisfying by my answer, please - grant me point - and create one more question.

Comment: Please study `befroeEach` block where **$q** is injected - and try implement **$routeParams** in the same way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256396/test-angularjs-controller-using-karma-jasmine...heres link of new question